# Как вывести случайное изображение на экран?

Tags: python

У меня есть девять изображений названных по принципу первое число, точка, второе число (например 1.1 2.3) мне нужно вывести случайное изображение по двум параметрам
код получился примерно такой:

```
import os
import random
a=random.randint(1,3)
b=random.randint(1,3)
os.startfile(r'D:\mt\a.b.png')
```

как написать последнюю строчку таким образом, чтобы систеа восприняла a.b как переменнные из которых формируется название, а не как название

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

```
r'D:\mt\%d.%d.png' % (a, b)
```

а можно и так

```
r'D:\mt\{}.{}.png'.format(a, b)
```

Если Python 3.6 или новее, то можно ещё так

```
rf'D:\mt\{a}.{b}.png'
```